# Can't stop ajax call by clicking cancel button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery script. The concept is, when I am clicking a button, it's first calling an AJAX function to count the no. of rows from a particular query. Then on successful call it stores the number of rows in a jQuery variable.

Then it calls an AJAX function which runs repeatedly to call data from server with 10 rows per time, during this process there is a progress bar which increases or fills gradually each time some data is fetched from the db. when a chunk of data is received, its getting pushed in a global array. When the last ajax call returns blank no. or rows, then the process terminates.

Besides there is a button along with the progress loader, which when will be clicked, will terminate the AJAX process to stop the call and display the data received till now in a data-table.

Here's my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var oTable;
var outer_start_row = 0;
var outer_limit = 1;
var final_data = []; 
var cancel = false;
var total_data = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.prettyPrint() && prettyPrint();
    $('#load').click(function()
    {
        var v = $('#drp_v').val();
        var cnt = $('#drp_cnt').val();
        var ctg = $('#drp_ctg').val();
        var api = $('#drp_api').val();
        var nt = $('#drp_nt').val();
        alert("version :"+v+" category :"+ctg+" country :"+cnt);
        $.post("ajax.php",
                {   
                    'version':v,'category':ctg,
                    'country':cnt,'network_id':nt,
                    'api':api,'func':'total_data'
                },
                function(data)
                {
                    total_data = data;
                    $("#progress_bar_container").fadeIn('fast');
                });

        load_data_in_datatable();
    });
});

function stop_it()
{
    cancel == true;
}


function load_data_in_datatable()
{
        if(cancel == true) 
        {
            alert(cancel);
            return;
        }   
        else
        {
        var v = $('#drp_v').val();
        var cnt = $('#drp_cnt').val();
        var ctg = $('#drp_ctg').val();
        var api = $('#drp_api').val();
        var nt = $('#drp_nt').val();
        $.post("ajax.php",
                {   
                'version':v,'category':ctg,
                'country':cnt,'network_id':nt,
                'api':api,'func':'show_datatable',
                'start_row':outer_start_row,'limit':outer_limit
                },
                function(response)
                {
                    var data = response.data;
                    var limits = response.limits;
                    outer_limit = limits.limit;
                    outer_start_row = limits.start_row;
                    if(data.length > 0)
                    {
                        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                        {
                            final_data.push(data[i]);
                        }
                        var current = parseInt(final_data.length);
                        percent_load = Math.round((current/parseInt(total_data))*100);
                        $(".progress-bar").css("width",percent_load+"%");
                        $(".progress-bar").text(percent_load+"%");
                        load_data_in_datatable();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        create_datatable();
                        cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }
                },'json');
        }       
}

function create_datatable()
{
    $("#progress_bar_container").fadeOut('fast');
    var aColumns = [];
    var columns = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < final_data.length; i++) 
    {
        if(i>0)
            break;
        keycolumns = Object.keys(final_data[i]); 
        for(j = 0; j < keycolumns.length; j++)
        {
            if($.inArray(keycolumns[j],aColumns.sTitle)<=0)
            {
                aColumns.push({sTitle: keycolumns[j]}) //Checks if
                columns.push(keycolumns[j]) //Checks if
            }                                  
        }

    }

    var oTable = $('#jsontable').dataTable({
        "columns":aColumns,
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "oTableTools": {
                "aButtons": [
                    {
                            "sExtends": "csv",
                            "sButtonText": "CSV",
                     }
                ]
            }
    });
    oTable.fnClearTable();
    var row = []
    for(var i = 0; i < final_data.length; i++) 
    {
        for(var c = 0; c < columns.length; c++) 
        {
                row.push( final_data[i][columns[c]] ) ;
        }
        oTable.fnAddData(row);
        row = [];
    }
}
</script>
```

The problem, is that I can't stop the AJAX when clicking on the cancel button.

Answer (score 1):

```
function stop_it() {
    cancel == true;
}
```

This function seems to be wrong, you need to assign **true** to the cancel variable but you have mistakenly written comparison operator(equal to/==) instead it should be:

```
function stop_it() {
    cancel = true;
}
```

I think you are calling this function while stopping AJAX in between the process.

Answer (score 0):

check link describe how you abort(stop/cancle) ajax request.

Jquery allows you to stop ajax request with .abort() method.

[Aborting an AJAX request](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/ajax/aborting-an-ajax-request/)

Comment: You just sent me a link..... i know how to abort.... i wanted to know about the logic of how it works

Comment: fine but you don't mention in question that you know .abort() function.you ask you want to stop ajax. pleas check your question.